# xml parsing in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

a simple little question. I have an xml file and im putting this xml file in an XML object

```
var receivedXML:XML
```

In some function, I have:

```
var xmlList:XMLList = new XMLList();
xmlList = receivedXML.some.attributes.here;
object.functionDoStuff = xmlList;
```

The function functionDoStuff takes xmlList as its argument:

```
function functionDoStuff(xmlList:XMLList) {}
```

When does receivedXML get parsed, is it when we assign it to xmlList, or is it when it gets used in the next instruction by the function functionDoStuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't parsed at either point.  It is parsed when receivedXML was created.  After that point it is an 'object' and not XML.

Comment: so when we call this instruction `object.functionDoStuff = xmlList;` there is no extra operations on the xml object, I mean like, it doesn't retrieve the children of receivedXML or something again, right?

Comment: Correct.  That has already been determined at that point.  You could change the data in the object - but the actual XML text representation is not considered at that point.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear enough, when we call object.functionDoStuff = xmlList, do we make an operation on receivedXML.some.attributes.here as well? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'make an operation'?

Comment: I mean does its value get changed when xmlList is changed?

Comment: No. The data is just taken directly from the XML object.

Comment: you means the XMLList object?

Comment: No - the XMLList object data is taken directly from the XML object (receivedXML).

Comment: I know, but if we change the value of the object xmlList, that doesn't change `receivedXML.some.attributes.here`, right?